# #1093 - You can't specify target table 'tbl' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql

Unable to execute below query

```
Update tbl SET alias_seq= (Select seq from tbl where analysed_object =
'data' order by seq LIMIT 1)
```

getting below error

> #1093 - You can't specify target table 'tbl' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot update the rows from the same data source which your sub query refers to.

Modify your query to this

```
UPDATE tbl SET alias_seq= (SELECT * FROM (Select seq from tbl where analysed_object = 'data' order by seq LIMIT 1) as X)
```

Here nested sub query makes a temporary table. So it doesn’t count as the same table you’re trying to update data from. In other words in `MySQL`, you can’t modify the same table which you use in the `SELECT` part.

You may refer here for more information  [UPDATE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html).

Comment: Thanks, it works for me

Comment: But it is updating same id to all records

Comment: how was it now ?

Comment: Problem solved, needed 1 more where Clause for outer query